# Implement RawRepresentable on UnitMass

Tags: swift, decorator, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to implement `RawRepresentable` on `Measurement<UnitMass>` and `UnitMass` in order to replace the following code with the `@AppStorage` decorator:

```swift
var unitOfMeasure: UnitMass {
    get { AppSettings.defaults.string(forKey: "unitOfMeasure").flatMap { UnitMass.fromSymbol(rawValue: $0) }! }
    set { AppSettings.defaults.set(newValue.symbol, forKey: "unitOfMeasure") }
}

var weightOverwrite: Measurement<UnitMass> {
    get { .init(value: AppSettings.defaults.double(forKey: "weightOverwrite"), unit: unitOfMeasure) }
    set { AppSettings.defaults.set(newValue.value, forKey: "weightOverwrite") }
}
```

How can I do this? I kinda achieved it using JSONEncoder/JSONDecoder:

```swift
extension Measurement: RawRepresentable {
    public init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8),
            let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Measurement.self, from: data)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        self = result
    }

    public var rawValue: String {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self),
            let result = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        else {
            return "{}"
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

But I fail to do it for UnitMass:

```swift
extension UnitMass: RawRepresentable {
    public init?(rawValue: String) {
        for unitMass in UnitMass.allCases where rawValue == unitLength.symbol {
            self = unitLength
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}
```

I get `Designated initializer cannot be declared in an extension of 'UnitMass'`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need your own `UnitMass` wrapper type, or give up the idea of using `AppStorage`. You can't conform `UnitMass` to `RawRepresentable`.

Comment: The sole purpose of `unitOfMeasure` seems to be to indicate the unit of `weightOverwrite`, but `weightOverwrite` is already a `Measurement<UnitMass>`, which contains unit information. Don't you only need _either one_ of them to conform to `RawRepresentable` here? You can just store `weightOverwrite` in user defaults, and `unitOfMeasure` can just return `weightOverwrite.unit`, right?

Comment: Kinda. The computed properties directly map to the configuration UI. The user can select the `unitOfMeasure` which directly effects the unit of the `weightOverwrite`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's why you cannot conform `UnitMass` to `RawRepresentable`.

`RawRepresentable` has the requirement that conforming classes must have an `init(rawValue:)` initialiser.

`UnitMass` is not `final`, so it can have subclasses.

Subclasses of `UnitMass` also conform to `RawRepresentable` if `UnitMass` conformed to `RawRepresentable`, so they must also have `init(rawValue:)`.

How would `init(rawValue:)` in the subclasses be implemented? Note that they can't just inherit the implementation in `UnitMass`, because subclasses could have their own stored properties that needs to be initialised in the initialiser.

So your extension requires all subclasses of `UnitMass` to implement this new initialiser. Well, extensions aren't supposed to add requirements - they are supposed to add functionality!

Even if extensions *can* do that, it would be impractical for you to go to every subclass of `UnitMass` and add an implementation of `init(rawValue:)` :)

Anyway, here are some workarounds:

Use a wrapper class:

```
class MyUnitMass: RawRepresentable {
    let unitMass: UnitMass
    
    var rawValue: String {
        unitMass.symbol
    }
    
    required init?(rawValue: String) {
        // assuming fromSymbol actually uses the correct converter
        unitMass = UnitMass.fromSymbol(rawValue: rawValue)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, save the `UnitMass` in `UserDefaults` as `Data` rather than `String`, because `UnitMass` conforms to `NSSecureCoding`.

```
let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: UnitMass.grams, requiringSecureCoding: false)

// save "data" to UserDefaults instead

let unitMass = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as! UnitMass
```

This has the advantage of also encoding the `converter`, without you having to hard code it in `fromSymbol` (presumably what you are doing right now).

Also note that if you are using the `unitOfMeasure` setting only as the unit for `weightOverwrite`, you should just save `weightOverwrite` in user defaults, and declare `unitOfMeasure` like this:

```
@AppStorage("hello", store: UserDefaults.standard)
var weightOverwrite: Measurement<UnitMass> = Measurement(value: 1, unit: .grams)

var unitOfMeasure: UnitMass {
    get { weightOverwrite.unit }
    set { weightOverwrite.convert(to: newValue) }
}
```

Comment: I actually came up with something similar like your last code snippet. But how can I get this into a Binding?

Comment: @LuMa `Binding` has a `get` and `set` initialiser: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/init(get:set:)-7ufcp

Comment: I understand, but this gives me `Cannot use instance member 'weightOverwrite' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`. Bummer, because I really preferred that solution.

Comment: @LuMa Ah, make it a `lazy var` then.

Comment: Got it, but one last thing; This yields a `Cannot find '$unitOfMeasure' in scope`? where it is used to bind it in the swiftui form

Comment: @LuMa Don't add the dollar sign. `unitOfMeasure` itself is the binding. You add the dollar sign when `unitOfMeasure` is a `State` or something, to turn it into a `Binding` (the projected value of `State`).

Comment: Also got that, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, either: A lazy property mutates the object on the first invocation and so will always be considered as mutating. This raises another error `Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'self' is immutable`.

Comment: I think we are quite close to a good solution, but this is too deep into SwiftUI territory, which I'm not too familiar with, so I'm afraid I can't help you more than that :(

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `RawReprresentable` itself, so that `UnitMass` starts conforming it automatically.

```
extension RawRepresentable where Self: NSSecureCoding {
var rawValue: String {
    let data = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self, requiringSecureCoding: false)
    return data!.base64EncodedString()
}

init?(rawValue: String) {
    if let data = Data(base64Encoded: rawValue), let unit = (try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data)) as? Self {
            self = unit
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

extension UnitMass: RawRepresentable { }
```